# Find mgf from joint pmf

Tags: self-study, distributions, density-function, joint-distribution, moment-generating-function

The joint pmf of random variables $ X$ and $ Y$ is given by 
$$p_{XY}(x,y)=
\begin{align}
& \frac{e^{-2}}{x! (y-x)!}\quad\text{if}\,\,\,x= 0,1,...y,\ y=0,1,... \\
\end{align}
$$
Find its mgf.

\begin{align}
M(t_{1},t_{2}) &=  E(e^{t_1 x+ t_2 y})\\
&= \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \sum_{x=0}^{y} e^{t_1 x+t_2 y} \frac{e^{-2}}{x! (y-x)!} \\
&=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} e^{-2} \frac{e^{t_2 y}}{y!} \sum_{x=0}^y e^{t_1 x} \frac{y!}{x!(y-x)!}\\
&=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} e^{-2} 2^y \frac{e^{t_2 y}}{y!}  \left(\frac{1+e^{t_1}}{2}\right)^{y}
\end{align}

How do I simplify further?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and detail where you get stuck in the derivation of $M$. Otherwise the question is prone to be voted down.

Answer (score 4):

**This problem is intriguing because it indicates something symmetrical lurks.**  One can't help feeling there is a simple, low-computation, insightful solution. Indeed, a little staring at the pmf suggests defining

$$z = y-x.$$

We may assume $z \ge 0$ (because when $z \lt 0$ the $z!$ terms in the denominator have poles, which makes those probabilities zero).  Now, for non-negative integers $x$ and $z$

$$p_{XY}(x,z) = e^{-2}\, \frac{1}{x!}\frac{1}{z!} = \frac{e^{-1}}{x!}\frac{e^{-1}}{z!} $$

is manifestly symmetric under exchanging $x$ and $z.$  **It is immediately recognizable as the probability distribution of two independent Poisson$(1)$ variables $X$ and $Z$ where $Z=Y-X.$**

Consequently--as you know, or can [look up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), or can easily compute, its moment generating function is

$$m_{XZ}(s,u) = E[e^{sX + uZ}] = E[e^{sX}]E[e^{uZ}] = \exp(e^s - 1)\exp(e^u-1)=\exp(e^s+e^u-2).$$

This function remains symmetric under an exchange of its arguments $s$ and $u.$ At this point we must break the symmetry to return to the original problem--but the calculations remain simple.  Since $Y=X+Z,$

$$\eqalign{
m_{XY}(s,t) &= E[e^{sX+tY}] = E[e^{sX + t(X+Z)}] = E[e^{(s+t)X+tZ}] = m_{XZ}(s+t, t) \\&= \exp(e^{s+t} + e^t - 2).
}$$

Even if your goal is only to simplify the sums you obtained, this insight into the variables and the underlying symmetric formulation can help guide your work.

Answer (score 3):

The joint pmf of $(X,Y)$ is of the form

\begin{align}
p(x,y)&=\frac{e^{-2}}{y!}\binom{y}{x}\mathbf1_{x=0,1,\ldots,y\,;\,y=0,1,\ldots}
\\&=\binom{y}{x}\frac{1}{2^y}\mathbf1_{x=0,1,\ldots,y}\,\frac{e^{-2}2^y}{y!}\mathbf1_{y=0,1,\ldots}
\end{align}

This shows that $X\mid Y\sim\mathsf{Bin}\left(Y,\frac{1}{2}\right)$, where $Y\sim\mathsf{Poisson}(2)$.

Using the law of total expectation:

\begin{align}
E\left[e^{t_1X+t_2Y}\right]&=E\left[E\left[e^{t_1X+t_2Y}\mid Y\right]\right]
\\&=E\left[e^{t_2Y}E\left[e^{t_1X}\mid Y\right]\right]
\end{align}

Now recall the MGF and PGF of binomial and poisson distribution respectively.

**Edit.**

To clarify, my hint above is the same thing as you have done. To finish it off, note that the last sum is just $E(a^Y)$ for some $a=a(t_1,t_2)$, which is just the PGF of $Y$.